# Where does the term non-singular (in non-singular matrices) come from?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, terminology, math-history

Non-singular matrices are invertible and has determinant $\neq 0$. Does the term non-singular come from the determinant being able to take more than one value (which is any non-zero real value)?

Comment: I'd say the term comes from the fact that a quadric is singular if its determinant is zero.

Comment: Non-singular doesn't mean invertible or having a nonzero determinant, at least in contemporary usage. It means injective. A square matrix $A$ is called non-singular if $Ax=0$ has only the trivial solution. E.g. over $\mathbb Z/6\mathbb Z$, the $1\times1$ matrix $A=2$ has a nonzero determinant, but it is singular (because $2\times3=0$) and hence not invertible. For infinite matrices (where we haven't the notion of determinant) over a field, non-singularity (injectiveness) is also not equivalent to invertibility (bijectiveness). The classical counterexample is the right shift.

Comment: In a wider sense : "singular" (exceptional) is antinomic from "regular" (ordinary). The word "singular" has taken its meaning of "non-invertible" a rather long time ago (I must track its earlier use ; I would say before 1900). Because of perplexities of some of my students (as you, apparently), I used to avoid it in my teaching, prefering the longer word "non-invertible"...

Comment: In ordinary English, the word "singular" can (somewhat rarely) be used to mean "unusual" or "exceptional".  This is presumably the origin of its various uses in mathematics.  (Although the mathematical usage likely first originated in another language (probably Latin) and then was borrowed into English.)

Comment: This might be a better question for https://hsm.stackexchange.com/ ("History of Science and Mathematics")

Comment: @GerryMyerson Didn't know that site existed. Thanks for letting me know! Also, thanks to everyone who left a comment.